# Implementing uniform cost search in prolog

Tags: prolog

I am new in prolog programming and just needed to ask that if there is a way to implement uniform cost search technique in prolog ?

Comment: Yes, surely there is, it's a general-purpose programming language

Comment: Prolog is a *Turing complete* language. This means it can emulate every other Turing complete language and thus by extent Java,... Since Java can implement uniform cost, Prolog can do this as well.

Comment: how come even iteration is possible in prolog there is no looping structure in it